# Q# Aggregate Exception Error

Tags: c#, q#

When coding with Q#, with the following code snippet I get an aggregate exception error (one or more errors seems to have occurred).

[image: code snippet]

What is wrong with this specific code snippet, and what parts of the Q# documentation have a bearing on this issue?

Code Snippet:

```
            // Try initial values
            Result[] initials = new Result[] { Result.Zero, Result.One };
            foreach (Result initial in initials)
            {
                BellTest.Run(sim, 1000, initial).Wait();
                var res = BellTest.Run(sim, 1000, initial).Result;
                var (numZeros, numOnes, agree) = res;
                System.Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Init:{initial,-4} 0s={numZeros,-4} 1s={numOnes,-4} agree={agree,-4}");
            }
```

Comment: Could you please include this code and Q# code which contains the definition of BellTest operation as code snippets that can be copy-pasted? It would make reproducing the error much easier

Comment: @MariiaMykhailova I can include the Q# code but I don't think its necessary since it's supposed to be an error caused by not using the wait or result key word

Comment: Can you please post the ```BellTest.Run``` code snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every call to a `Q#` operation is asynchronous, as execution on actual hardware will also be asynchronous, thus every time you call `Run` you must wait for the execution to complete before you can execute another quantum operation. There are multiple ways to wait for an asynchronous `Task` to finish, including using the [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await) keyword, the [`Wait()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635(v=vs.110).aspx), or retrieving the [`Result`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `Task`.

In this particular case, you invoke `BellTest.Run` twice, and the second doesn't wait for the first to be completed. The Exeption will go away if you add `Wait()` to your first `Run`, for example:

```
    BellTest.Run(sim, 1000, initial).Wait();
```

Comment: Why is he calling BellTest.Run twice and why is one waiting and the other returning a result?

Answer (score 0):

look at your innerException
the problem is a null reference exception. 
Debug your code and make sure that nothing is null.

> BellTest, sim, intinial or  BellTest.Run(sim,1000,intinial)